# Runas not allowing complicated commands

Tags: batch-file, windows-server-2003, runas

I've been working on this SVN post-commit hook batch file for awhile now, and I've encountered yet another problem. This is all done on a Windows 2003 server machine.

I'm trying to execute this line as the admin (This works when executed by itself):

```
START "game_server" CMD /k ""C:\Program Files\nodejs\"node.exe "C:\Program Files\nodejs\game_server.js""
```

And I've tested this, and it also works as I expected it would:

```
runas /savecred /user:admin_account CMD
```

But when I combine the two into this:

```
runas /savecred /user:admin_account "START "game_server" CMD /k ""C:\Program Files\nodejs\"node.exe "C:\Program Files\nodejs\game_server.js"""
```

Then I get the "runas usage" ouput, which basically amounts to runas /? info.  The exterior " wrapper around START and at the end was added after it failed without.  So both ways were tested.

The fact that I seem to be unable to combine two simple commands makes me think I'm just brainless today, so please, tell me what obvious thing I am missing.

Comment: Huhn, interesting, *checks file* that's not in the file, I must have deleted a character while formatting the post. -- Fixed it in post, also, not that it matters much, but that was simply the title of the CMD window -- only important when I'm using taskkill to close it later.

Comment: As a workaround, can you make a batch file that does nothing but launch the server and call runas on that?  Might be easier.

Comment: @Wug that does seem like a perfectly reasonable option.  It won't help my curiosity on what's going on here, but it should get my task completed. Thanks for the clarity.  (I often get stuck on solving problems that don't need to be solved...)

Comment: It's probably related to retarded handling of literal quotes.  One shortcoming of batch is that everything nesting more than 2 levels of literal quotes becomes indecipherable moonrunes.